# How can I get body parser to parse emoticons?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, body-parser

I have the following middleware in Express:

```
app.use(morgan('combined', util.getLogStream()));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb' }));
app.use('/api', router);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/server/landing'));
```

When I try to POST emoticons to my server, the line `app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb' }));` breaks and crashes the server to crash. I am searching for a way to handle emoticons in Express or body parser but there seems to be little support for this. How can I get body parser to parse emoticons?

EDIT:

This is the message payload I am sending via curl to my Express server

```
curl --data '{"x": 10, "y":10, "z":10, "message": "", "userToken": "Marine"}' --header "Content-Type:application/json” localhost:3000/api/messages


**Error message**

Uncovery listening at http://:::3000
SyntaxError: Unexpected token
    at Object.parse (native)
    at parse (/Users/user/Documents/uncovery/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:84:17)
    at /Users/user/Documents/uncovery/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:102:18
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/Users/user/Documents/uncovery/node_modules/body-parser/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:149:7)
    at IncomingMessage.g (events.js:199:16)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:104:17)
    at _stream_readable.js:908:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
```

**index.html**

```
var http = require('http');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var express = require('express');
var socketIO = require('socket.io');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var util = require('./server/core/utilities.js');
var router = require('./server/routes/router.js');
var sockets = require('./server/routes/sockets.js');

var app = express();
var server = http.Server(app);

app.use(morgan('combined', util.getLogStream()));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.json);
app.use('/api', router);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/server/landing'));

var io = socketIO(server);
sockets.initialize(io);

server.listen(3000, function () {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;
  console.log('Uncovery listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

Comment: Can you show us the request payload that's causing the crash? I ran a quick bodyParser experiment posting the following JSON body: `{"blah": ""}` and it seems to work fine.

Comment: Your charset definition in your header ends strangely (not actual quote). Is that actually what you're sending or was there a copy/paste issue?

Comment: What version of express are you using? I noticed you required `bodyParser` but you're still using the built in express one for json requests. Try this instead: `app.use(bodyParser.json());`

Comment: Checkout my index.js, I am using bodyParser.json(). My current express version:   4.12.3